# \newcommand with PythonTeX PyCode

Tags: macros

Environments are MiKTeX 2.9, XeLaTeX, PythonTeX 0.11 beta, and Python 3.3.
I am pretty new to LaTeX and Python/PythonTeX and am struggling with the following piece of code.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfopts}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newcommand{\pow}[2]{\py{#1**#2}}
\newcommand{\poww}[2]{\pyc{print(#1**#2)}}
\newcommand{\powww}[2]{\begin{pycode}print(#1**#2) \end{pycode}}

\begin{document}
\pow{2}{5}      % success
\poww{2}{6}     % success
\powww{2}{7}    % fail
\end{document}
```

I get an error on `\powww` and can not understand why. Any help appreciated.

```
Extraneous input `print(2**7) \end {pycode}^^I% fail' between \begin{pycode}[
<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ...ncyVerb Error:^^J\space \space #1^^J}

l.28 \powww{2}{7}^^I% fail
```

The ultimate goal is to pass sets of 2 unicode strings as parameters from the XeLaTeX document via PythonTeX to Python, but I prefer to "start simple and then expand step by step".

Answer (score 3):

PythonTeX environments, like the pycode environment, cannot be used inline.  There must be a linebreak after the `\begin{pycode}`, and the `\end{pycode}` must be on a line by itself as well.  Also, PythonTeX *environments* cannot be used inside LaTeX commands.  This limitation is due to the way LaTeX deals with verbatim (literal) text in environments (it's related to TeX's catcodes).

If you want to create custom commands, `\py` and `\pyc` are the way to go.  If you want to create a command that involves more complex code, then you should probably define a function in a pycode environment, and call that function within `\py` or `\pyc`.

If you have additional questions, you might ask them on https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: thanks. Before creating this question I also tried \powww...\pycode ... with code all on separate line,s which failed as well. But that is then due to not being able to use pycode within latex cmds.